# random number generator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random

I am trying to generate 10 random numbers in Haskell `mkStdGen` in the range of 0 (inclusive) to 100 (exclusive).

Something equivalent of the following Java code

```
Random ran = new Random();
ran.nextInt(100);
```

Note, I have to use `mkStdGen`

This is what I have so far


`rand low high seed = fst (randomR (low, high) (mkStdGen seed))

randomlist :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]

randomlist l h num = take num (map (rand l h) [0..])`

Comment: Is this homework?  Can you show us what code you've got so far?

Comment: next (mkStdGen 3) is what I have so far, I am still reading the documentation.  But have a specific code snippet that would does ran.nextInt(100) would make things a lot easier to understand.

Comment: ...most haskell documentation doesn't like giving concrete example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import System.Random

tenPseudorandomNumbers :: Int -> [Int]
tenPseudorandomNumbers seed = take 10 . randomRs (0, 99) . mkStdGen $ seed
```

Note that this isn't really pseudorandom, because `mkStdGen` takes an explicit seed. `newStdGen` would be better, if you're allowed to run in `IO`.

Comment: Well, it's not truly random in any case, it's always a PRNG. If you acquire the seed in the same way impure languages do (e.g. reading from `/dev/urand`, of whatever Java does by default), this is just as pseudo-random as the Java example.

Comment: True; I shall edit to say that it's not even really pseudorandom.

Comment: I would suggest refactoring as `pseudoRandoms :: StdGen -> Int -> [Int]`, passing the generator and bound as arguments, then you can obtain the generator in whichever way is available, `mkStdGen` or `newStdGen` and use it in a pure manner even if it came from IO. Tacking on a `take k` at the end can be left to the user without problems.

Comment: @dave4420 ahh, i figured it out b4 I saw ur solution.  credit to you anyway

Comment: It *is* pseudo random by most reasonable definitions of pseudorandom. As it says in wikipedia, "The sequence is not truly random in that it is completely determined by a relatively small set of initial values", exactly describing your code. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)